# Affecting the last Category in a list

Tags: categories, ifelse

I have this code:

> {categories}{category_name}, {/categories}

Outputting in a Entries Tag Pair.

I would like to remove the comma from the last outputted category only. I am thinking an IF statement but am not really sure what would be appropriate for this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the backspace parameter.

"Backspacing removes characters (including spaces and line breaks) from the last iteration of the loop."

```
{categories backspace="2"}{category_name}, {/categories}
```